# How to debug a bug occurs only in the real iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, devtools

My website works well on desktop version and on DevTools mobile phone simulator.

However, when running in the real iPhone 11, when clicking an element, it seems the click event does not fire. I need to click again and then the website will response.

This only occurs on the real iPhone, not on the DevTools mobile phone simulator. How can I debug the codes to solve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various methods.

1. Use a service like Browserstack/Lamdatest
   https://www.browserstack.com/
   https://www.lambdatest.com/

they have various devices including android/ios/windows/Linux/mac where you can test web apps.

2. macOS with simulators.
3. MacOS with a real device can be debugged by safari/xCode by enabling inspectors mode in the device setting.
   https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/

Comment: For 2 and 3, does that means I need to purchase a new mac laptop to perform the test?

Comment: yea(if you don't have an old one). You can not debug a real iPhone on windows/Linux. Option 1 is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I am tired of all this barriers, addons, paied services to do something that should be simple.

So I made this simple JS code, you can edit as your will:

```js
var debuggerEl;
function debug(m){
    if(!debuggerEl){
        debuggerEl = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(debuggerEl);
    }
    debuggerEl.innerHTML = debuggerEl.innerHTML + "<br/>" + m;
}
console.log = m => debug("LOG: " + m);
console.error = m => debug("ERROR: " + m);
console.exception = m => debug("EXCEPT: " + m);
console.warn = m => debug("WARN: " + m);
```